# Why it is significantly slower to reference global variables in a for loop?

Tags: c

I was reading a book which says to use local variables to eliminate unnecessary memory references.  For example, the code below is not very efficient:

```
int gsum;  //global sum variable
void foo(int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       gsum += i;
    }
}
```

It is more efficient to have the code below:

```
void foo(int num) {
    int fsum;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       fsum += i;
    }
    gsum = fsum;
}
```

I know the second case uses a local variable which is stored in a register.  That's why it is a little bit faster while, in the first case, `gsum` has to be retrieved from main memory too many times.

But I still have questions:

Q1- Isn't the the gcc compiler smart enough to detect it and implicitly use a register to store the global variable so that subsequent references will use the register exactly as the second case?

Q2- If, for some reason, the compiler is not able to optimize, then we still have the cache.  Referencing a global variable from the cache is still very fast but I see that some programs which use local variables are 10 times faster than the ones who reference global variables.  Why is this?

Comment: Check out [what actually happens](https://godbolt.org/).  The generated code is essentially `if (num > 0) gsum += num * num;` with no loop at all.  Note that if `num` is negative, the behavior is undefined since integer overflow must occur, so the compiler can do as it pleases in that case (here, nothing at all).

Comment: In that example, gcc actually does `gsum += num * (num - 1) + num;` for reasons I don't understand.  clang doesn't do that.   Possibly just a missed optimization (or perhaps un-missed pessimization).

Comment: But change it to something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/9YboPs) that's not so easily expressed in closed form, and you'll see the compiler does exactly what you suggest.  The value is kept in a register throughout the loop and only stored back at the end.

Comment: A trickier case is if you call a (non-inlined) function in the loop.  The compiler can't know whether the function accesses the global variable, so it has to store and reload it around every function call.  If you know that doesn't happen, then using a local variable instead could help.

Comment: Second version use an uninitiated `fsum`, set it o `0` or `gsum` Global variables are guaranteed to be 0 local are not.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: That register is probably going to be needed by other functions which will be called between subsequent calls to `foo`.  That means `gsum` will need to be shuttled in and out of the register whenever this function is called.

Q2: It's possible that the page containing `gsum` will stay in cache for a while.  However, depending on what else your computer is doing, that page may get written to swap space in order to make room in memory for other pages.